# Preprocessing a REST request for BASIC authentication on tomcat + JAX-RS

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jax-rs, interceptor

I'm developing a REST api and i want to use apply BASIC authentication on it.

What i want to do :

1. Intercept request for methods like `GET, PUT, POST, DELETE`.
2. Fetch **username** and **password** from **authorization header**.
3. Authenticate User by validating UserName + Password from database.
4. Accordingly allow or deny access to service.

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7, JAX-RS for this project.

So what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Write a `ServletFilter` to intercept all the incoming request to your REST web services. Depending on the authentication, `doFilter` the request to your REST webservice or deny with 401.